# How to handle error status in ES6 Promises?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

I am using ES6 and trying to handle error status of the `fetch()` result.

I know I can catch error like this:

```
fetch(`http://${this.serverAddress}/reset`)
        .then((resp) => {
            Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(resp));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
```

In `catch` block I take an `Error` with message "Failed to fetch". There is no status information.

I have found the following suggestion:

```
fetch('/some/url/')
  .then(processResponse)
  .then(response => {
    // do something
  })
  .catch(response => {
    // repsonses with status >= 400 get rejected. you can access response.status and response.data here too
    if (response.status === 400) {
        // handle form validation errors, response.data.errors...
    } else if (response.status === 403) {
        // handle permission errors
    } // etc
  });
```

But `response.status` is *undefined* in `catch` block.

How can I get status code of the error to handle it?

**UPDATE**:

Thank you for the responces. Please see my updates:

My actual token looks as `http://api.service/v2/prices/latest?token=err`. If I write my token instead of `err`, then it works. When I try this URL, my code go to the `catch` block, not `then`.

I noticed the following error in browser console:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

If I add `{mode: "no-cors"}`, code go to the `then`, but status is always 0. This is not that I want.

I tried to add

```
mode: "cors",
headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
```

This is not help, I still have `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header` error.

Comment: You should do that checking in `processResponse`, which has access to the `response` object (and you can return `Promise.reject(...)` with whatever you want)

Answer (score 1):

You may try to handle the error status by throwing error during response processing right after the fetch is done with `!ok`:

```
fetch('/some/url/')
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw Error({ status: response.status });
    }
    response.json();
  })
  .then(response => {
    // do something
  })
  .catch(error => {
    switch(error.status) {
      // ...
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the docs the `catch` block will be reached only if the request didn't complete. When there is a status code available (and all the other data is received as well) `fetch` will resolve and therefore the `then` block will be reached.

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing. - [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

So all you have to do is logging `resp.status` instead of `resp`.

```
fetch(`http://${this.serverAddress}/reset`)
  .then((resp) => {
    Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(resp.status));
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    Logger.debug(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

> In catch block I take an Error with message "Failed to fetch". There is no status information.

So in case the `catch` block is getting called the request didn't even finish. This might be caused because you are not using options like `method`, `headers`,... If needed, which one and what values depends on the backend you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can't check the status in code.

> The Promise returned from fetch() won’t reject on HTTP error status
>   even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, it will resolve
>   normally (with ok status set to false), and it will only reject on
>   network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.

Basically, fetch() will only reject a promise if a  networking error occurs.

The fetch API provides a simple ok flag that indicates whether an HTTP response’s status code is in the successful range or not. See the below example

```
fetch("http://httpstat.us/500")
    .then(function(res) {
        if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
        return res;
    }).then(function(res) {
        console.log("ok");
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: It is possible to check the status code. Though not within the ```catch``` block but in the ```then``` block.

Answer (score 0):

After the fetch request check if response is as expected. If not, throw new error with a custom message. In the catch check if this custom message is there for the thrown error. Handle accordingly.
You can also create custom **Errors** and check the same.